# Install MySQL on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL on ubuntu 16.04. I've looked through various posts on here and serverfault to try and resolve the issue but it still persists.

I installed MySQL using:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Then after setting the root password the install just hangs on:

```
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
```

I've purged and rebooted, no luck.

---

```
Oct 11 11:56:40 ip-172-31-47-249 systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Oct 11 11:56:41 ip-172-31-47-249 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Oct 11 11:56:45 ip-172-31-47-249 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 11 11:57:07 ip-172-31-47-249 dhclient[895]: DHCPREQUEST of 172.31.47.249 on eth0 to 172.31.32.1 port 67 (xid=0x132b1603)
Oct 11 11:57:07 ip-172-31-47-249 dhclient[895]: DHCPACK of 172.31.47.249 from 172.31.32.1
Oct 11 11:57:08 ip-172-31-47-249 dhclient[895]: bound to 172.31.47.249 -- renewal in 1677 seconds.
Oct 11 11:57:22 ip-172-31-47-249 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Oct 11 11:57:22 ip-172-31-47-249 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 11 11:57:22 ip-172-31-47-249 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 11 11:57:22 ip-172-31-47-249 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 11 11:57:22 ip-172-31-47-249 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Oct 11 11:57:22 ip-172-31-47-249 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server..
```

Answer (score 0):

taken from [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1571865):

```
[Workaround Option 1/3]

To reset your MySQL configuration back to defaults,
type "sudo update-alternatives --remove my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.migrated" after the upgrade.
Then use "sudo service mysql start" to start the MySQL daemon
and "sudo apt-get -f install" to recover your system packaging state.
```

Comment: Thanks, after running the above I now get: mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.

Comment: You tried to connect to the MySQL Server while it was upgrading? The error you are receiving just means that the user `deb-sys-maint` has no access to the sql-server can you try again with `root`?

Comment: I can log into mysql with root. But when I try to dpkg --configure - to configure it it just errors with the above error.

Comment: But youre Server functions as expected/works as usual?
About the deb-sys-main: look at this [Answer on Serverfault about deb-sys-maint](http://serverfault.com/a/9952/315718)

Comment: Yes I've done exactly as those answers suggest. Still get the same error.

Comment: just this one answer should solve your problem: http://serverfault.com/a/9957/365121
But if this fails AND you do not have any valuable data in /var/lib/mysql, you can always remove all mysql-server-\* packages, /var/lib/mysql and /etc/mysql and start over.

Comment: I've tried out that post, Im running select * from mysql.user; and it just comes up empty after adding the debian user. Please help!

Comment: Did you try @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann 's suggestion about starting all over?

Comment: Ive started over a few times now.

Comment: anything in /var/log/syslog ?

Comment: yes lots of stuff like mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Comment: would you please add the output of syslog to your question?

Comment: have updated question with relevant output of log